# Pro*C in oracle XE

Tags: compiler-construction, oracle-xe, oracle-pro-c

I downloaded the free express edition of oracle, Oracle XE. I couldn't find the Pro*C compiler in this edition. I read somewhere that Oracle 9i client has Pro*C, so I presumed that Oracle client for 10g XE should have it too and downloaded it. But to my disappointment, I can't find it there.

Is there a way to download the older oracle 9i and use it connect to 10g XE without any compatibility problems?. Or is it possible to download the Pro*C compiler alone?

I don't want to download the standard editions as they are too large (2 GB).

Answer (score 1):

**SHORT ANSWER:** For XE, you will need to download and install the 10g client into a new software home.

**BACKGROUND:** The pro*c precompiler for 10g was actually not released with the database software installation, but only in the separate client installation.

**ADDITIONAL INFO:** If you were working with anything other than XE, you can use the client installation to "Add" to the existing database install.

Comment: Blog on this :http://oradim.blogspot.com/2009/05/oracle-proc-on-windows-with-express.html

Comment: weird that in 9 years you never got credit for a great answer - thanks !