# Pro*C installion on Ubuntu

Tags: c, oracle, oracle-pro-c

I installed both Oracle client and server on Ubuntu 11.04 Desktop x86. But when I try to compile [this C program](http://www.orafaq.com/scripts/proc/select.txt) using the Pro*C `SAMPLE.PC` I get this message:

```
No command 'proc' found, did you mean:
 Command 'nproc' from package 'coreutils' (main)
 Command 'proj' from package 'proj-bin' (universe)
proc: command not found
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [pro*C in oracle XE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839303/proc-in-oracle-xe)

Comment: Given the Ubuntu mention, I assume you are using XE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to reinstall the Oracle Client

Answer (score 0):

Its like u wouldnt have selected the pro*c packages while installing oracle.